# SQL connection pool starvation before making any connection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core

When running my microservice developed with ASP.NET Core and EF Core (latest versions) I started getting this error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

This is very strange, as it worked fine until tomorrow. SQL database is hosted in Docker.

This exception is thrown by code:

```
try
{
    using var c = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection();
    var cconstrcc = c.ConnectionString;
    var dbstate = c.State;
    c.Open(); // <- exception thrown
    ctx.Database.OpenConnection();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

This is only test code, because application just hangs when I try to run query `dbContext.SomeTable.ToList()` (does not work with `async` version as well), and I am unable to see why and when it happens (I suspected some deadlock maybe).

This is very very strange, as it happens on the first attempt to connect to database.

I was inspecting SQL Server Monitor, SQL Server Profiler and also run stored procedure `sp_who`, but I don't see ANYTHING, any connection made from my app, it's like SQL pool exhausts immediately.

Also, we used dependency injection everywhere, but I have gone through all context usages and switched it to local variable with

```
using var ctx = new DbContext();
```

to make sure I close every connection. Issue is still exactly the same.

#### UPDATE

But I also run some test application (console app) and made connection simply by using `SqlConnection` object, without any ORM - it worked.

#### UPDATE

Also tried to go back in history with `git checkout` to point where it was definietely working - to my surprise, that version also hangs and does not work.

### UPDATE

Changing from IIS to Kestrel resolved the issue, connections are made successfully. So it's IIS related bug ?

Comment: Have you logged into the database and checked whether there are unexpected connections there?

Comment: If you switch it back to IIS does the problem return? We get a higher level of timeouts in Docker than in other environments (but that is just one data point, obviously).

Comment: @mjwills Yes, nothing there... It's my local DB, so I would be surprised if there were any connections made :D (i don't run any software which could connect to my db)

Comment: @mjwills No, it still hangs...

Comment: `using var c = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection();` will create the DbConnection, then immediately Dispose it because the `using` scope has finished. In the using pattern you normally enclose code depending on that object inside code blocks, e.g.: `using (var foo = new Something()) { ... Do; Stuff; Here; ... }`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations

Comment: @MichałTurczyn neat, I learned something new today.